# Hive regular expression working issue

Tags: regex, hive

I have a string like given below

```
"ITheme:Sports,Genre:SportingEvent,Genre:Sports,Genre:Football,Genre:Pro,ITheme:Football"
```

if I use the following query it only returns me the first match for genre i.e SportingEvents

```
select split(regexp_extract(coalesce('ITheme:Sports,Genre:SportingEvent,Genre:Sports,Genre:Football,Genre:Pro,ITheme:Football'), '(Genre:.[^,]+)', 0),':')[1]
```

I want a output in separate columns like

> ```
>                     Genre
> ```

```
       SportingEvent,Sports, Football
```

Comment: Do you see this nice and (unfortunately not so shining) edit button? Really, your question is hard to read.

Comment: you got it wrong genre is the column name in the output

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the above question but for a large dataset it will take lot of time

`select collect_set(myCol2)
from
(
select myCol1,regexp_extract(myCol1,'Genre:(.*)',1) as myCol2
from
(
select split('ITheme:Sports,Genre:SportingEvent,Genre:Sports,Genre:Football,Genre:Pro,ITheme:Football',',') as a
) v1
LATERAL VIEW explode(v1.a) myTable1 AS myCol1
) v2
where myCol2 != ''`

Answer (score 0):

This will also work
`select 
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace('ITheme:Sports,Genre:SportingEvent,Genre:Sports,Genre:Football,Genre:Pro,ITheme:Football','((\\w*)(?<!ITheme):.[^,]*)','')
,'(^,)|(,$)',''
)
, ',{2,}', ','
)
,
'Genre:',''
) as Genre`